# Scattering of two particles - phase factor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

I did see some posts on stackexchange on this matter, but I find them to be beyond my scope or not directly related to what I am looking for.

I am reading Feynman Lectures III, chapter 4. It talks about scattering of two particles $a$ and $b$ and it defines $f(\theta)$ to be the probability amplitude of particle $a$ scattering at angle $\theta$. Then it says

"You might also think that the amplitude for the second process (where particle $b$ instead enters the detector placed at angle $\theta$) is just $f(\pi-\theta)$. But that is not necessarily so, because there could be an arbitrary phase factor."

I'm not questioning why things behave the way they are in quantum mechanics. But, isn't it ***by definition of $f$*** that the probability amplitude of particle $a$ scattering at angle $\pi-\theta$ is $f(\pi-\theta)$? I don't see why there is a phase factor. If there's a phase factor, it should already be part of $f$.